# Unable to find or target elements in an iframe using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I'm trying to write a C# Selenium script to change the size of an item on: http://automationpractice.com/index.php

I'm not able to target anything in the iframe popup even after trying to switch to the frame first.

To get the iframe to show I clicked the quick view of item 1 using:

```
var element = 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"homefeatured\"]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/img"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Click();
actions.Perform();
```

This then showed the iframe window but I can't find anything in it even after trying to switch to the window with:

frame 3 is what the firefox ide selected.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(3);
```

selecting the default and then selecting different frames.

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

trying to use the frame name

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("fancybox-margin fancybox-lock");
```

trying frame id's 0,1,2,3

It never finds any of the elements by XPath, ID, Name or anything else. I'm trying to get the size drop down to change.

The XPath I'm looking for even though I've tried a lot of other higher up levels is

```
//*[@id="group_1"]
```

Any help really appreciated I've been stuck for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to switch, it would work, Id consist of some number at the end and also it keeps changing.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(By.Xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'fancybox-frame')]"));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, It's showing that it cannot convert an OpenQA.Selenium.By to an int error when using it?

Comment: @RonaldMcD Please do some research on how to write on C#, I don't know C#, I am using Selenium Ruby Binding(WATIR). I checked it works very fine, I decided to write an answer because I understood the problem.

Comment: Sorry if the thanks for helping sounded sarcastic it was genuine for trying to assist.

Comment: @RonaldMcD Hey absolutely not a problem, actually I don't know C#, that's why I said you. Do you know Ruby? If you know Ruby you can use WATIR which sits on the top of Ruby Selenium Binding, you don't even need to switch the frame there WATIR takes care of everything automatically. Do you want to give a try?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue finally, there was another iframe further down so it was failing as it was targeting elements in iframe 1 or 2 after navigating into iframe 3. Also needed to add a delay before finding the element as it was searching before the iframe finished loading.